# pytables, add rows in nested field

Tags: python, nested, pytables

Starting from a simple structure like this one:

```
from tables import *

class subTable(IsDescription):
    subCol1= Int64Col(pos=0)
    subCol2= StringCol(itemsize=32, pos=1)
    subCol3= Int64Col(pos=2)

class mainTable(IsDescription):
    column1= Int64Col(pos=0)
    column2= StringCol(itemsize=32, pos=1)
    column3= subTable()
```

If I understood the documentation good, now I have a table (mainTable), with 3 columns `(column1, column2, column3)` that has another table contained in each `column3`, with another 3 columns `(subCol1, subCol2, subCol3)`

So, now, filling the main table with rows is an easy job.

However....what to do to add rows to each table inside `column3`??

Of course, If I am wrong I would appreciate any correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with PyTables.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is not wrong, it's just that I don't think you can have multiple rows for the `subTable`:

```
from tables import *

class subTable(IsDescription):
    subCol1= Int64Col(pos=0)
    subCol2= StringCol(itemsize=32, pos=1)
    subCol3= Int64Col(pos=2)

class mainTable(IsDescription):
    column1= Int64Col(pos=0)
    column2= StringCol(itemsize=32, pos=1)
    column3= subTable()

hdf5_a = openFile("delete.hdf5", "a")
table = hdf5_a.create_table("/", "test", mainTable)

table.row['column3/subCol1'] = 10
table.append()
```

So you can put values for `subTable` with `table.row['column3/subColX']`. But not multiple rows.